# getting error 400 in device oauth flow

Tags: facebook, oauth

When making an http post:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device?type=device_code&client_id=myclientid
```

I'm getting an http 400 error. Am I doing something wrong here? Is device_code supposed be something other than device_code? It doesn't look that way here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/

I'm just starting to experment with browserless facebook auth.

Answer (score 1):

Well, clicking https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/device?type=device_code&client_id=myclientid gets you a pretty clear error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported type: 'device_code'. Supported types: web_server, user_agent, client_cred, username",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

The [linked specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-05#section-3.7.1) though says:

```
type
         REQUIRED.  The parameter value MUST be set to "device_code".
```

As [Facebook is stating](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/):

> Both the specification and our implementation are constantly being refined, however, so some subtle differences should be expected.

that could be some temporary glitch between implementation and documentation.

Anyway, are you sure you already would have access to device authentication?

> Please note that we are currently testing Device Authentication with a limited number of partners. It is not currently available for general use, and we are not accepting additional applications for access.

Comment: This is probably due to the note at the top of the docs explaining that it's not publicly available

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following URL(only the appId is changed) you will get result. It will return a code, id, verification URI etc. The fact is that the device flow api will work only for the above appId and which is provided by facebook. No other AppIds wont work. Everything will return an  error like this

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported type: 'device_code'. Supported types: web_server, user_agent, client_cred, username",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 1
         }
}
```